# Writing to file multi dimensional NSMutableArray problems

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am having trouble writing and retrieving a multidimensional array from a file. I add all the objects I want to write into an array and write and retrieve the array from a file it creates. All of the other objects beside the multidimensional array are reading and writing properly except for the multidimensional NSMutable array Object.

I writing the array using:

```
[array addObject:multiDiminutionalArray];
[array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
```

I read the array using:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
multiDiminutionalArray = [array objectAtIndex:1];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Two important questions: What do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: Agree with Chuck. These things don't usually fail silently so if it's not working, don't assume we have a crystal ball with which to divine what's going on. Post your errors. Also, you're not even checking the BOOL return value from -writeToFile:... so how do you know if it was even successfully written? You need to do a better job checking the results of your calls (see "defensive programming").

Answer (score 0):

YuzaKen should've made the comment into an answer.

I suspect lack of NSCoding conformance for the class(es) of one or more of the objects stored in your array is the issue. NSArray knows how to archive itself but do the objects stored in it?

Alternatively, make sure your file path is a valid file path. If it's something like @"myFile.dat" it's not valid because it's not a full path. If it's something like @"~/Desktop/myFile.dat" it's also not valid because the tilde isn't expanded to the full /Users/me/... path.